Stucco cracks, caulking, and painting
Currently having the exterior of my stucco house painted. Painters were supposed to use stucco patch but instead filled cracks with the same white caulk they used everywhere. Cracks range up to about half an inch wide.
With the damage/bad repair now "done", what is a reasonable course of action or ask? It seems like it will be incredibly difficult to remove the caulk, maybe impossibly so in a way that leaves it clean for a proper product to bond well. Aside from poor aesthetics with the texture difference and overage, how problematic will this be for me down the road?
Sample image attached.


Stucco patch is generally prescribed for repair of larger areas, where chunks of stucco have been knocked off.
Where there are cracks, it is prefered to fill with a caulk that has properties to expand and contract so the crack is unlikely to reappear.
If it were my home I would be upset if the work on cracks was done with stucco patch, as I know they would be likely to reappear.  I have lived in Fla. for almost 40 years and found many a crack in stucco. Always repaired with caulk rather than stucco patch.
